# Trying to position a div below a button, but having trouble aligning it to the right side of the button

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using react, and I have a row of buttons, and one of these buttons should open a div that contains some information on click.

I'm having some trouble with the css though.  Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ovxw4eg/1/

And the snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.openItem {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button class="test">
    The Button
  </button>
</div>

<div class="openItem">
  This should be below and to the right edge of The Button
</div>
```

How should I approach this issue?  I'm using a flex box for the row of buttons.

My react code has a check where if `someProp` is `true`, then show this box.  ie.  `showPopup && renderPopup`

Comment: Use value like "left: 260px;" on .openItem but it would only work until the window size gets small enough to resize the buttons.

Comment: Post a [mcve] **in your question please**

Comment: In openItem class css, add bottom - 0px.

Answer (score 0):

Move the div inside of the container div of the buttons and use inline-flex and position relative on it.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.openItem {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button class="test">
    The Button
  </button>
  <div class="openItem">
    This should be below and to the right edge of The Button
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.openItem {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button>
    some button
  </button>
  <button class="test">
    The Button
  </button>
  <div class="openItem">
    This should be below and to the right edge of The Button
  </div>
</div>
```